# Does H'shem makes it harder to grow spiritually on purpose?

Tags: hashgacha-pratit

I heard that, sometimes, H'shem makes it harder to grow spiritually so that we can appreciate better our growth when we finally conquer high spiritual levels. It is true? If so, what is the source?

Comment: I believe the Ramchal says so outright in the beginning of Derech Hashem. I don't know the exact place, and he likely is not the original source.

Comment: I thought that was the entire purpose of the *satan*?

Comment: The hardness is there so you can be Mitgaber and overcome it. And there's no finality - there are always more levels infinitely upwards. https://www.sefaria.org/Likutei_Etzot%2C_Obstacles_and_Inhibitions.1?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en